# Can mundane equipment be bought between sessions in Adventurers League play?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league

When playing in D&D Adventurers League, are players allowed to buy mundane gear out of the PHB between sessions or does this have to happen in front of a DM?

I have read that mundane gear not marked as treasure on an adventure is not able to be kept after the session. Is there anything to let future DMs know my character bought those caltrops and did not illegally salvage them from a dungeon?

Answer (score 6):

Adventurer's League functions on the honor system. As long as your log sheet records the appropriate funds in (from adventure rewards) and the appropriate funds out (from purchases of mundane equipment), you shouldn't have any problems.

Certain activities, like downtime spent Copying Spells, requires the presence of a DM because they involve rolls. If there's no roll involved, you don't need a DM. Check out the [Player's Pack](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack) and the [DM Pack](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/208179/DD-Adventurers-League-DM-Pack) for more precise details.

Anything from the Player's Handbook is fair game. Anything from the DMG is off-limits for cash purchases, except as adventure rewards. For example, you can buy all the basic *Potions of Healing* you want, because they're in the PHB, but you can't buy the more potent versions, because they only appear in the DMG.

Comment: When you say anything PBH is fair game, does this include mounts? Could I buy a pack of mastiffs for hunting, and/or a horse and wagon?

Comment: @saviorself7 If it has a price in the PHB, you can buy it.